# How well does Indonesian public transport run around around the New Year?

Tags: public-transport, indonesia, public-holidays, bali, jakarta

I am considering backpacking (train/bus/boat) from Jakarta to Bali during the few days before and after New Year.

In some countries that would not be a good idea as trains are fully booked (*and most restaurants/attractions are close*). How about this part of Indonesia? Are there things to be aware of during that period?

Comment: There's a volcano on...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Yes, that's another topic ^_^

Comment: The volcano might make any answers based on previous experiences than accurate, tho.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: 95% of the route is very far from the volcano, the biggest consequence I could see is more people using non-plane transport. I could just cancel the remaining 5% if there are still problems with the volcano in 3 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cool!

New year and Chrismas are not massive events in Java island. There will be more people than usual on the road, but nothing compared to the "[Balik Kampung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balik_Kampung)".

It will be school holiday and Chinese population might be in christmas holiday in their familly. But for most people, this is business as usual.